# WMI IIS 6.0 Custom HttpError (Powershell)

Tags: iis, powershell, wmi

please can someone look over this and tell me what I am doing wrong?
I am trying to modifiy the Custom Error message property's in an IIS website using powershell and wmi... This is what I have come up with.

```
    $Server = "localhost" 
    $Wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class IIsWebServerSetting -Namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" -ComputerName $server -filter "ServerComment = 'SharePoint - SP80'" -Authentication 6
    $CustomHttpError = $wmi | Foreach-Object { $_.HttpErrors | ? {$_.HttpErrorCode -contains "400"} | Select HttpErrorCode, HttpErrorSubcode, HandlerType,HandlerLocation;}
    $CustomHttpError.HandlerLocation('C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\Custom.htm')
```

I get the Error message "Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementBaseObject] doesn't contain a method named 'HandlerLocation' "

When I use Get-Member to inspect  $CustomHttpError I get the following.

TypeName: Selected.System.Management.ManagementBaseObject

Name             MemberType   Definition
----             ----------   ----------
Equals           Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode      Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType          Method       type GetType()
ToString         Method       string ToString()
HandlerLocation  NoteProperty System.String HandlerLocation=C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\400.htm
HandlerType      NoteProperty System.String HandlerType=FILE
HttpErrorCode    NoteProperty System.String HttpErrorCode=400
HttpErrorSubcode NoteProperty System.String HttpErrorSubcode=*

How do I modify the HandlerLocation Property if it is not a method I can invoke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$Server = "localhost" 
$Wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class IIsWebServerSetting -Namespace "root\microsoftiisv2" -ComputerName $server -filter "ServerComment = 'SharePoint - SP80'" -Authentication 6

#Get httperrors array
$HttpErrors = $wmi.HttpErrors
#Changing 400 error pages
$HttpErrors | % { if ($_.HttpErrorCode -eq "400") { $_.HandlerLocation = "C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common\Custom.htm" } }

#Set updated httpserros property
$wmi.HttpErrors = $HttpErrors
#Save object
$wmi.Put()
```

Comment: Graimer, Thank you this works, I see where I was going wrong thank you for the help.

Comment: np :) for future questions. when you provide `get-member`, DON'T use `select .....` on the object before. When you use `select` you create a new object containing ONLY the properties you specified, and not all that was available in ex. this wmi-object. :-)